# Create table from another table.(Sql Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create a new table same as some existing table plus some additional columns. In simple case we will do as:

```
 Select * INTO table2 from table1 where 1=0
```

But I also want to add some new columns. Can we do it in one step i.e. without using `ALTER TABLE` as next step?

Comment: Are the new column values derived from the older table columns?

Comment: Be aware that this is not a good way to create a new table if this is in some sort of procedure that will get run multiple times. Select into only works once.  Also no indexes/ PKs/Fks will not get created for the new table the new table. follow the table when you create it this way. Identity fields will go to the new table. So you may nee to explicitly create these things if you need them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but in order to specify the data types, you should cast null as the desired type.

```
SELECT *
, CAST(NULL as NVARCHAR(100)) as NewColumn1
, CAST(NULL as INT) as NewColumn2

INTO B
FROM A
WHERE 1=0
```

Column constraints/defaults will need to be added separately via an UPDATE TABLE statement, but they may not be necessary for what you are trying to do.

The column types certainly will be.

Comment: Null will automatically cast as an integer, so yes if you will eventually fill this up with some other type of data, you need to cast this. I learned this one the hard way!

Answer (score 1):

Can you explicitly list the new columns in the `SELECT` statement? Do they need to be populated or can you just have empty fields?  Something like

```
Select *, cast(NULL as type) as NewColumn1, cast(NULL as type) as NewColumn2... INTO table2 from table1 where 1=0
```

Although you might have to list all of the individual columns from the original table rather than `*`, too.

Comment: Probably want `cast(null as type) as ColumnName` to control what type the columns are.

Answer (score 0):

You can do It in following:

```
SELECT *, 
       '' AS Col2, -- Here you can specify you new columns
       '' AS Col3  ---------------------------------------
INTO table2 
FROM table1
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this

Select *, 'abc' as city into dbo.newtable from dbo.oldtable where 1=0

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add more `columns` add those in the `select` statement:
eg:

```
select 
  t.*, 
  12 as ID, 
  'ABCD' as Name 
INTO table2 
from table1 as t 
where 1 = 0
```

After `creation` do a `execute sp_columns 'table2'` to see the definition of the table as you expected.
Here `Name` column will be of type `varchar` of length `4`.